# Is there a limit to the amount of displayable Toasts?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, limit, toast

In the MainActivity I need to show all files returned by `getApplicationContext().fileList()` but only about the first 50 Toast will be displayed.

There is some limit for that?

```
String[] fileList = getApplicationContext().fileList();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileList.length + " files", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

for (String fileName : fileList)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There *has* to be a better option than showing an individual `Toast` per file. If this is for your debugging purposes, use `Log` and Logcat. If this is for the user, use a `RecyclerView` to show them in a list.

Comment: @CommonsWare It's for my debugging purpose but while the device isn't attached to pc. So Logcat cannot help me in this case. Maybe a good solution to show a dialog with a ScrollView inside it? By doing so I must not alter the UI of the Activity. Thanks

Comment: Look into [the various debug drawer implementations](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/218?sort=created). Or, connect `adb` over WiFi, so you still have Logcat access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update February 2023

A new [limit](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r34:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java;l=351) of 5 queued toasts was added in Android 12, [preventing to queue too many toasts](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r34:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java;l=3236-3240).

```
// To limit bad UX of seeing a toast many seconds after if was triggered.
static final int MAX_PACKAGE_TOASTS = 5;
```

```
if (count >= MAX_PACKAGE_TOASTS) {
    Slog.e(TAG, "Package has already queued " + count
            + " toasts. Not showing more. Package=" + pkg);
    return;
}
```

Also the [previous limit of 50 toasts](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r47:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java;l=286) was changed to 25 in Android 10.

```
static final int MAX_PACKAGE_NOTIFICATIONS = 25;
```

### Original answer

Yes, toasts are queued and there is a limit of 50 toasts, you can see the check for it in [`NotificationManagerService`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-5.0.0_r7.0.1:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java;l=1032-1036) class

```
if (count >= MAX_PACKAGE_NOTIFICATIONS) {
    Slog.e(TAG, "Package has already posted " +
           + " toasts. Not showing more. Package=" + pkg);
    return;
}
```

And `MAX_PACKAGE_NOTIFICATIONS` is declared as

```
static final int MAX_PACKAGE_NOTIFICATIONS = 50;
```

Comment: Funny. I get this error message: 'Package has already queued 5 toasts. Not showing more. Package=com.lni.health.at.home.' I guess Android got cheap.

Comment: @BrianReinhold It looks like a new limit was added in Android 12 because of the UX concerns.

Comment: One could wait 2000 ms or 3500 ms until showing the next toast to bypass that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is possible that all of your Toasts are displaying, **but** because you have `LENGTH_LONG` in your toats some of them are displaying before the previous Toast is finished and they are overlapping each other so seems like you don't see them all.

As *@CommonsWare* said in his comment, is this is for your debugging better use `Log`.